# Summing up values of overlapping polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, union, summarizing

I have large single layers with many features overlapping.

Simplified example with 50% transparency:

[image]

Where the features overlap I want the attributes added together. I manually created the output I want below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 17):

**QGIS 3.2**

Thanks to new [**Union**](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog32/#feature-union-algorithm-with-a-single-layer) tool in QGIS 3.2, this has become quite easy!!!

What we do, is just use **Union** and **Aggregate** tools.

(1) **Union** (`Processing Toolbox | Vetor Overlay | Union`)

[image]

(2) We obtain `Union` layer (now broken into 12 parts...sorry mostly hidden...)

[image]

(3) **Aggregate** (`Processing Toolbox | Vector geometry | Aggregate`)

Note: `Group by` expression is `geom_to_wkt( $geometry )` and the `Aggregate function` is `sum`

[image]

(4) Final output is `Aggregated` layer.

[image]

Comment: Any tip on how to achieve the same result in posgis SQL ?

Answer (score 7):

**Before QGIS 3.2**

This example requires MS-Excel function, along with SAGA in QGIS Processing Toolbox.

(1) Start **Polygon self-intersection** tool in `QGIS Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Vector polygon tools`. A trick here is to select your `value` field as **Identifier**.

[image]

(2) This tool adds an attribute field **ID** which shows values of all intersected polygons, separated by a **|** (pipe) in between.

[image] *do not use `id`*

So, please avoid using `id` for a fieldname. (The `id` above is really bad example, which will be troublesome later when we save it as csv).  Maybe `fid` or `code` would be fine.

(3) All overlapping feature will be given id: zero (0). Please edit and assign unique number. Save it as a csv file, and open by Microsoft Excel.

(4) In Excel, run `Convert Text to Columns Wizard` tool. (Choose **|** as the separator). Calculate sum of them (eg column F as sum of C,D,E in this example).

[image]

(5) Keep columns `fid` and `sum` and remove all the others. Save it as new csv file.

(6)  Join the new csv file with the polygon layer using `fid` as the key field.

Lots of things to do... Not a pleasant way, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'test2'* with some overlapping features in it, see the image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Apply the SAGA's ["Polygon Self-Intersection"](https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/2.1.4/shapes_polygons_12.html) tool

[image: step1]

*Note:* After applying this algorithm some fields from the input original layer become meaningless. Therefore the ["Drop field(s)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#drop-field-s) algorithm can be useful.

**Step 2.** Use a bit of the ["Field Calculator"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) for:

1. counting overlaps

   ```
   array_length(string_to_array("ID",'|',1))
   ```

   [image: result1]
2. summing values of a certain field e.g. `"num"`

   ```
    array_sum(
        array_foreach(
            string_to_array("ID",'|',"ID"),
            attribute(
                get_feature('test2', 'id', to_int(@element)),
                'num'
                )
            )
        )
   ```

   [image: result2]