# Creating Raster that sums up input polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, buffer, fields-attributes

I am using QGIS and I have a shapefile with buildings. From these buildings, I have made a Buffer with variegating radius. The Buffer also have data about the demand for Parking spots for each building.

How do I build a raster that accumulates the data of the Buffer?

Each pixel should sum up the attribute (demand of Parking spots) of all the buffer zones that overlay each other on this particular point(pixel).

My aim with this raster is to show: "From this pixel I can serve so and so much parking demand (from the surrounding buildings)".

[image: That's how the Buffers look like]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210959/how-to-sum-up-values-of-overlapping-polygons-in-qgis

Comment: may I ask, why does it have to be a raster? it seems like a job for vector data, considering one might want to relate that demand to, say, a road network. of course there might as well be a good reason for raster data...just not a straight forward way to get it, I think.

Comment: I want to build a cost raster with several different layers. But it is very possible that I am using a more complex method than necessary :(