# Creating iso-contours of cumulative values of overlapping polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, summarizing

I start by drawing polygons by hand and assigning each polygon an attribute value for a frequency (or probability). What I then need is to create a heat map or iso-contours that show the cumulative probability at each point (that is covered by one or more polygons). The scale of these contours should be logarithmic.

I've been trying to play around with the polygons that I create, using the Union function and Centroids, but I can't figure out how to get the overlaps to sum all the values of this specific attribute, and produce a visualization of that data. Where do I start?

Below is an example of what the data may look like, and what type of end-result graph I'd like to produce. ( The actual numbers in the example don't add up correctly...)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'test'* (blue polygons).

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Apply the ["Union"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#union) geoalgorithm

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** ["Delete duplicate geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicate-geometries)

**Step 3.** Convert ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts)

**Step 4.** In the ["Field Calculator"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) use the following expression (with [`overlay_intersects()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects) function):

```
array_sum(overlay_intersects('test', "Value"))
```

to sum all the values of the `"Value"` attribute

[image: step_3]

**Step 5.** Get the ["Centroids"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#centroids)

[image: step_5]

**Step 6.** ["Extract vertices"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-vertices) from the polygons achieved at the *step 3*

[image: step_6]

**Step 7.** ["Merge"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#merge-vector-layers) the results of *steps 5 and 6*

[image: step_7]

**Step 8.** Proceed with the ["Contour"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/contour/) Plugin to generate contours for the `"NewValue"` field, to get the following result

[image: result]

Comment: Thank so much for the response! Unfortunately, I end up with some error in Step 3 - the resulting table either end up with NULL values in the new field ("NewValue"), or I get values that don't add up correctly as yours do in the example. What "number type" should I choose for the Field "Value"? Length and precision? I end up with different results when I play around with there, but never correct...

Comment: I used Real data type for `"Value"` and `"NewValue"` fields

Comment: When I create a new ShapeFile layer, I can only choose: Text(String), Integer (32bit), Decimal(Double) or Date - for NewField/Type. I must do something wrong. Your table shown in Step 3: for me, all (7) rows end up with NewValue=0.111

Comment: Try the `Decimal(Double)`. Is it possible to share your data?

Comment: Thanks again for your resonses! I ended up solving my needs by using the first method in this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210959/summing-up-values-of-overlapping-polygons-in-qgis - the one for QGIS 3.2, and then playing around with layer styles, logarithmic intervals for coloring - producing a nice enough map.